# Is it possible to run android GUI emulator in Jenkins using a .bat file?

Tags: android, batch-file, jenkins, android-emulator, jobs

I have in my project a .bat file that runs locally, automatically an android emulator. But when I'm on jenkins it doesn't. It should be noted that I am running on a Windows operating system.

**file .java**

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(RELATIVE_SOURCE_BAT);`

**file .bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd \
c:
cd C:\android-sdk\emulator
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29
endlocal
```

```
Started by user Abraham
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test
[Test] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins8592026279839913802.bat

C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test>setlocal

C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Test>cd \ 

C:\>c:

C:\>cd C:\android-sdk\emulator 

C:\android-sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_29 
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
added library vulkan-1.dll
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
dsound: Could not set cooperative level for window 0000000000000000
dsound: Reason: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function
audio: Could not init `dsound' audio driver
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:288: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
WARNING: change of renderer detected.
emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(136, 100), size=(300x21), dirty=(300x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
```

Comment: Please paste in the error you are getting while trying to run the .bat file in Jenkins.

Comment: @Sourav Atta, I just uploaded the result that shows jenkins, but it does not finish executing, it keeps loading (it has already been 8 minutes)